# Easier way to solve a LES (only pen/paper, no calculator)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I want to solve the following Linear Equation System with *only* pen and paper;

$$
470 = x_A - \frac{3}{10}x_B \tag{1}
$$
$$
940 = x_B - \frac{2}{10}x_A \tag{2}
$$

I attempt to solve for $x_A$ by inserting equation (2) into (1) and rewriting it, etc. I got something like;

$$
x_A=470 +\frac{3}{10}(940+\frac{2}{10}x_A) \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow x_A\frac{94}{100}=470+\frac{3}{10}940=470+\frac{2820}{10}
$$

Next I try to isolate $x_A$ and simplify the expression;

$$
\dots \Rightarrow x_A =\frac{100}{94}(470+\frac{2820}{10})=\frac{100}{94}(470+282)=\frac{100}{94}752
$$

This is where I get stuck. Have I dug myself into a difficult hole when there is a better/more efficient approach to solving this LES? Or am I just missing a good method to solve $x_A=\frac{100}{94}\cdot752$ to get it to 800?

Any insight into "how to think" here and how you solve it with just pen and paper is much appreciated.

(Solution: $x_A=800$, $x_B=1100$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice $94=47\cdot 2$. You can simplify before adding/multiplying:
$$x_A\frac{94}{100}=470+\frac{3}{10}940\color{red}{=470+\frac{2820}{10}} \Rightarrow \\
x_A\frac{47\cdot 2}{100}=47\cdot 10+\frac3{10}\cdot 47\cdot 20 \Rightarrow \\
x_A\frac2{100}=10+\frac{60}{10} \Rightarrow \\
2x_A=1000+600 \Rightarrow \\
x_A=800.$$

Comment: Ok, but why do we focus on factorizing 94 into 47 and 2? Is it because we have 940 and 470 on the RHS?

Comment: yes, look for common factors

Comment: Thanks for your help. Wouldn't it be more intuitive if the red text is $470+\frac{3}{10}\cdot470\cdot2$?

Comment: the first line is yours and the red text implies it must be deleted, only black text is the right solution. in other words, you should not write this red text (it is an error)

Comment: ah, thanks, that makes perfect sense!!

Comment: you are welcome. the more problems one solves, the more trained the eyes get to notice the connections between parts.

Answer (score 1):

May be, it could be simpler to do $$470 = x_A - \frac{3}{10}x_B \implies4700=10x_A-3x_B\tag{1}$$

$$940 = x_B - \frac{2}{10}x_A \implies9400=10x_B-2x_A\tag{2}$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $10$ and $(2)$ by $3$ and add them together; this gives immediately $$75200=94 x_A\implies x_A=\frac{75200}{94}=800$$ Plug this in $(2)$ to get $x_B$

Comment: Thanks! But with pen and paper, how do you compute 75200/94 ?

Comment: @litmus. By hand !!

Comment: Could you please tell me the name of the method used for this so I can google it.

Comment: @litmus. Have a look at  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SystemsTwoVrble.aspx

Comment: But this link explains how to solve Linear Systems, I would like to know how you solve 75200/94 by hand. Please show me, this would help me so much!

Comment: @litmus https://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html

Comment: Merci Claude Leibovici!

Answer (score 0):

What are your problems ?

$ x_A=\frac{100}{94}\cdot752$ is correct, since $752:94=8.$

Comment: But how do you see that 752 divided by 94 is 8? I.e. how do you get to 800?

Comment: $90 \times 8=720$ and $4 \times 8=32.$

Comment: Could you please elaborate, do you use 90 and 4 because they sum to 94?

Comment: Yes, we have 90+4=94

Comment: Thanks for your help! But how do you know to decompose 752 into 720 and 32? (If you don't know that $x_A=800$)